# Generate a .h file along with the DLL in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c, delphi, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have some C code that I need to use in a Delphi Application. Using cmake, I can generate a solution in Visual Studio 2012 that compiles it into a DLL. It would take forever and a day for me to write all the import units in Delphi for all the functions. There is a tool i could use to convert the DLL .h file into pascal import units, but Visual Studio doesn't give me the .h file for the DLL.

So what are my options?:

1. Do I have to go and get all the .h files from the .c files and compile them into one file myself?
2. Is there a way to get Visual Studio to make a .h for the DLL during compile?
3. Is there anything else i can try to get the DLL into Delphi for use in another application?

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to provide.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the developer of the C code would also produce a header file. Do you know why is there not one? Or perhaps you just have not found it yet.

You aren't going to find a good tool to make a header file for you. In any case though, you don't want a header file. You want a Pascal import file. Even if you had a header file, there is no good tool to convert from there to Pascal import file. There are tools that attempt the job, but my experience with them is that they don't work well.

They can only work well if the C code has extra annotations, and they seldom do. For instance, how should this be translated:

```
int foo(int, int*);
```

Is the `int*` argument a scalar or an array? If the former, is the parameter optional? Can `NULL` be passed? If the latter, how long is the array? A basic header file does not provide a complete specification.

I'd say that the best course of action would be to write the Pascal import code by hand. If there is a lot of repetition then you could write your own small tools to help. That's what I always do anyway.

Comment: There are .h files for each of the .c files, but to compile them together and adapt them to work with the DLL is going to be a mission. Isn't there a way to compile the code to something which the Delphi Import Component wizard can understand?

Comment: I think I already answered this already. It feels like you didn't read the answer. What do you want a header file for? What is Delphi going to do with it? How many functions do you need to call? Surely you'd be finished by now if you'd started work when you asked the question.

Comment: I can go ahead and start doing it all by hand, but there are a lot of functions, probably around 100 or more. Also, there are a lot of complex data types that will need to be converted as well.

Comment: There aren't any shortcuts here.